# Navigate from Jetpack Compose to Fragment and from Fragment to Jetpack Compose Screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I go from Jetpack compose screen to fragment and from fragment to jetpack compose screen? I use the jetpack compose navigation? any help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have a hybrid app with both compose and view system fragments then the recommendation is to host all your composable screens in fragments and use the fragment navigation. When you are ready to go all in with compose you can then switch to compose navigation.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#interoperability) for reference.

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#fragments-in-compose) is the recommended way of doing it per Google.

1. Enable view binding
2. Make sure your Activity is an AppCompatActivity
3. Create a layout for the fragment container:

   ```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.compose.snippets.interop.MyFragment" />
   ```
4. make sure you have declared the compose viewbinding dependency `androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding`
5. Create the Composable containing the Fragment:

   ```
    @Composable
    fun FragmentInComposeExample() {
        AndroidViewBinding(MyFragmentLayoutBinding::inflate) {
            val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<MyFragment>()
            // ...
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Why is `data binding` necessary?

Comment: I didn't try without, I suppose you could but there will be more to do to correctly handle the lifecycle of the fragment.

Comment: Google does not recommend Data Binding anymore.  Use ViewBinding instead.

Comment: I meant view binding in there

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I wrote data binding

Answer (score -2):

You can use AndroidView() and ComposeView() for this

https://youtu.be/PjQdFmiDgwk